# JMeter Monitoring Issues

Tags: jmeter

I'm not getting the results I expect when I use JMeter to monitor my server. Here's how I set up my monitoring:

1. Add a Thread Group element.

   - The Thread Group tells JMeter the number of threads you want. Always use 1, since we are using JMeter as a monitor. This is very important for those not familiar with server monitors. As a general rule, using multiple threads for a single server is bad and can create significant stress.
   - Change the loop count to forever (or some large number) so that enough samples are generated.
2. Add the HTTP Authorization Manager to the Thread Group element.

   - (Add –> Config element –> HTTP Authorization Manager).
   - Enter the username and password for your webserver.
   - Important note: the monitor only works with Tomcat5 build 5.0.19 and newer.
   - Leave the base URL blank
3. Add the HTTP Request to the Thread Group element

   - (Add –> Sampler –> HTTP Request).
   - Select the HTTP Request element in the tree and edit the following properties:

     - Change the Name field to “Server Status”.
     - Enter the IP address or Hostname
     - Enter the port number
     - Set the Path field to “/manager/status” if you’re using Tomcat.
     - Add a request parameter named “XML” in uppercase. Give it a value of “true” in lowercase.
     - Check “Use as Monitor” at the bottom of the sampler
4. Add a Constant timer to this thread group.

   - (Add –> Timer –> Constant Timer)
   - Enter 5000 milliseconds in the “Thread Delay” box.

     - In general, using intervals shorter than 5 seconds will add stress to your server.
     - Find out what is an acceptable interval before you deploy the monitor in your production environment.

Comment: Can you be more specific of what your actual question is?  What do you mean by "shows result dead". There also seems to be alot of information in your repro steps that are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Jist use this PerfMon for Jmeter: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PerfMon